# Is it possible to override ONE axis of a CSS background-position using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I am using CSS sprites to build a six-tab-menu. Since the tabs overlap, I decided to use six versions of the image in the sprite, one for each active tab state (one below the other). So I need to change more than one tab for each state because of adjacent overlaps, so I might as well just change the position of all of them.

In the menu each link in the menu has its own CSS background defined from the sprite image. It all fits together nicely.

What I'd like to do is add a class to the body that would change the **vertical** position of all the link backgrounds without having to define the **horizontal** so that the horizontal position can be inherited. This way I only need to define six more classes to make it work instead six of them for each state (=36).

Some equivalent of `background-position:inherit -94px`.

I can do it easily with jQuery, but was hoping for a CSS-only solution.

[image]

Comment: I think, it's a bad idea, how you do it. Just imagine, if you change 'ITME2' with 'ITEMLONG2'. You need to change the hole grafix. I would opt for sliding doors ( http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/ )

Comment: Check out http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y

Comment: yunzen: If the menu changes, our graphics department will provide new artwork, no biggie. Sliding doors will result in too many elements to manage and has its own set of complications.

Comment: Yeah, Snook is a pretty good resource. If he can't make it work, I guess it's jQuery to the rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't be done. Mostly because firefox doesn't support `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` though understandable because its not part of the specs.

I had this problem myself not long ago but brief investigation told me it was still not possible.

I am going to asume you have a sprite you want to use for multiple states of the menu. In this case you should just split up the sprite in 2, one for state a and one for state b, and when you add the class you simply switch over to image b with `background-image`.

It's ofcourse one more image but there really isn't a crossbrowser way to just shift one axis.

Comment: I thought so. I was hoping there would be some CSS3 technique by now. I ended up doing it in a couple of lines of jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 got the explanation as to why it wasn't included in the spec with http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y its the exact same article that I scooped up when researching.

Comment: "Elika and Bert considered the use case too weak to introduce new properties" I'm glad the future of CSS background positioning came down to the opinions of two people. *Sigh*

Comment: Its easy to talk about this afterwards but they're just human, we miss things and you could also say other people missed this usecase which might have convinced them otherwise, but that is all in the past now... Lets hope that in a few years all vendors support it regardless of the specs.